# I can't install Manjaro (Watchdog BUG)

Tags: linux, windows-10, installation, uefi, manjaro

I'm trying to install Manjaro in this computer:

- MB: ASRock Z75 Pro3
- CPU: I3-3220
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6800
- RAM: 8GB
- BIOS: UEFI American Megatrends ICN 2.00, 2013/10/9
- SMBIOS version: 2.7.
- SSD with two HDD in RAID as a slave
- Windows 10

I've done the next actions:

- I disabled SecureBoot
- I disabled Fastboot
- I have checked the ISO of Manjaro
- I made the bootable USB again (Rufus and Etcher) with 3 different USB sticks.
- I started with restart+shift (win) and selecting the UEFI USB Manjaro installation (and also the Legacy before)
- I tried with Puppy Linux also and get similar results (when it is loading kernels in the installation process I get a black screen)
- I tried with Puppy in DD mode (Rufus)
- I checked that the disk is in a GPT mode
- I tried with Arcolinux broking the PC (solved now)
- I tried with `nomodeset nolapic` with `watchdog BUG` with both, free and non free drivers.
- KDE Neon was installed very easy.

The best that I get is the Watchdog BUG.

Any idea?

EDIT:
After so many tries I could install KDE Neon straightforward (I think clear CMOS helped to that), so I discard Manjaro for a while, at least until I see an easy way to do it.

Comment: When creating the USB in Rufus, does it prompt you to select "ISO mode" vs "DD mode"? Which one are you selecting?

Comment: @user1686 Rufus doesn't give me that option. I saw some tutorials that suggest to use "DD MODE", but I haven't that option in my computer with my USB stick and the last version of Rufus.

Comment: In Rufus 3.x, the option is hidden from the main window, instead it shows up as a dialog box _after_ you've clicked "Start". (Whether it shows up depends on the ISO being written, not on the USB stick.)

Comment: @user1686 I have that option with Puppy Linux but not with Manjaro KDE.

Comment: I tried with Puppy in DD mode with the same black screen result.

Comment: Have you tried the user guide (includes installing) https://manjaro.org/support/userguide/

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm editing the main post adding steps that I'm doing.

Comment: What exactly is your computer model, especially regarding the motherboard, CPU and GPU? Are you on the latest BIOS version?

Comment: Could you please answer the above comment?

Comment: Sorry @harrymc, I've been trying and learning about other solutions. Here my answer. MB: ASRock Z75 Pro3, CPU: I3-3220, GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6800, RAM: 8GB, BIOS: UEFI American Megatrends ICN P1.80, 05/12/2021, SMBIOS version: 2.7. I'm going to update right now the BIOS.

Comment: Your BIOS can't be from 2021 ... In any case, the [ASRock BIOS page](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z75%20Pro3/index.asp#BIOS) has version 2.00 from 2013/10/9 and also version [Beta] 2.10 from 2018/5/30.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo mistake (2012). I have upgrade to the last 2.00 BIOS. I couldn't install Manjaro, with the same black screen failure.

Comment: Try to add the following parameters to the Live boot : `nomodeset nolapic` ([link](https://askubuntu.com/a/470527/963426)).

Comment: Trying another solution to this QA I have broken more my PC. Now I can't even start the BIOS, I can't see anything! any idea to solve this? I have broken trying install Arcolinux.

Comment: If the file EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi doesn't exist on the pendrive then you don't have an EFI bootable disk.  Generally GPT partitions go with EFI boot and MBR partitions go with MBR boot.  This is related but separate to UEFI secure boot.  Usually enabling "legacy mode" in the BIOS will allow MBR booting.

Comment: @AMGMNPLK: You may need to [clear the CMOS](http://forum.asrock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=630&title=how-to-clear-cmos-via-battery-removal).

Comment: Yes @harrymc, that worked! Now I'm going with your solution about Linux installation.

Comment: @davolfman, that file seems to look like it exist, at least I can see that option inside de EFI option in the GRUB.

Comment: @harrymc It seems to work also! I have added `quiet splash acpi=off nolapic nomodeset` as @KWubbufetowicz notice in the link that you have attached. Let it finish the process, and the bounty is yours :)

Comment: I get a `watchdog:  BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [systemd-udevd : 362].` error. I added only `nomodeset nolapic` and I have this problem also. I'm researching.

Comment: It was with `nonfree` drivers, with free drivers I get the same BUG but with `[systemd-udevd:359]`

Comment: Try to add the minimum possible, which is only `nomodeset nolapic`.

Comment: I tried with that also, same problem.

Comment: Well, I tried and I have could install KDE Neon. Then, I don't understand where was the first error with all distros that I tried, but after Clean CMOS I installed it straightforward. Manjaro still with that problems. I'm a bit tired of trying, so I think that I would keep KDE Neon if I don't see a clear way to install Manjaro. Thanks @harrymc, the bounty is for you. Do you have any idea about how to install Manjaro correctly?

Comment: I assume that you are already installing Manjaro correctly, there aren't too many ways of doing it after all. ASRock computers are notoriously hard to install Linux, so I think that Manjaro is just not compatible enough. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Answer was added.

Answer (score 2):

The poster has not been able to install Manjaro Linux on his ASRock Z75 Pro3,
although he did manage to install another Linux distribution, KDE Neon in
this case.

The following steps made it possible:

[**Clearing the CMOS**](http://forum.asrock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=630&title=how-to-clear-cmos-via-battery-removal):

> 1. Disconnect the system's power from the wall
> 2. Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds to be sure residual power is discharged
> 3. Place the "Clear CMOS" jumper in the clear position
> 4. Remove the CMOS battery
> 5. Leave the system in this state for 4 hours. 10 minutes is enough in most cases but if that yields no result then to be absolutely certain
>      CMOS is clear I recommend 4 hours.
> 6. Place the "Clear CMOS" jumper back in its original position
> 7. Replace the CMOS battery
> 8. Power on the system

[**Kernel boot options**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470492/ubuntu-14-04-black-screen-when-installing)

The following was added to the kernel booting options : `nomodeset nolapic`.

Note: `nolapic` means having only a single cpu and core visible and should be
disabled for later usage.

Comment: I installed without the `nomodeset nolapic`, but it works to run (with error) the installation of Manjaro that before didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the processor, memory and GPU (if any) you are using? From what you described it looks to me something to do with the kernel...

If you have an "old" kernel on the live iso, it may not have the correct drivers for your hardware. I can suggest you to download an [[ISO of Arcolinux][1],](http://[ISO%20of%20ArcoLinux][https://sourceforge.net/projects/arcolinux/files/ArcoLinux/]) they release monthly live ISOs so the user can test it and later perform the OS  installation. It can boot on UEFI or MBR.

If this Arcolinux ISO boots it means your Manjaro or Puppy have a Kernel that doesn't recognize for some reason your hardware.

In case it does not boot, I'd like you to try to boot on MBR and share the results.

Comment: I've just edited the question with that info. I'm going to update the BIOS and after that take your advice. Thanks

Comment: I got a blue screen after the update. I'm restoring the pc now.

Comment: Sorry, I understand you got a Blue Screen after booting on Windows... Did you do any configuration on the Bios or just upgraded it?

Comment: Yes, blue screen trying to boot Windows after just upgrade BIOS. I'm going to try also with the Arcolinux because the restoring seems not to work, maybe I can skip the Windows restoration.

Comment: The Win10 restoration looks like is working now.

Comment: This is getting worst. I restored Win correctly and made a USB with Arcolinux. I rebooted (in UEFI mode), opened the installation menu, selected the installation a I get another black screen, with the inconvenience that I can't boot neither the BIOS.

Comment: It is really awkward. It seems not to be able to even go to the Kernel phase. I am getting out of ideas here...

Comment: Any idea about why I have a brick and how to solve it @vxp ?

Comment: Sorry, first for the late reply, second because I cannot see a solution for your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try a different USB device.

I don't see that in your list of troubleshooting efforts.  I had somewhat similar results of Debian 10's installer only partially working, and in frustration one of my students tried a different USB stick and better results occurred.  We could try to "made the bootable USB again (Rufus and Etcher)" multiple times over, but it turned out to be a hardware issue (solved by re-purposing that hardware to be a Memtest86 boot stick).

Comment: If you're selecting time zones, you've definitely accomplished what is typically the hardest part, so UEFI Secureboot settings are unlikely to be the issue.  Persist.  It sounds like you might just be a kernel parameter away from success.

Comment: I have tried with 3 USB sticks. Any idea more?